# React - Array of children components not rerendering with props expression set in a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I understand that the wording of the question is slightly nebulous, so I will expand. This is a personal project of mine that I have taken up to learn some React basics and familiarize myself with socket.io

I have a CollapsibleList component, and a NestedList component, which renders an array of the CollapsibleList components.

NestedList has an event handler that gets set in componentWillMount of the component. The event is when a menu arrives via socket.io from my server. When the menu arrives, a new CollapsibleList is added to the array, and state is changed to trigger a rerender. The events are triggered by an initial socket.io event that is emitted via componentDidMount (get-menus).

CollapsibleList is collapsed/uncollapsed by its onclick which uses a toggleVisiblity method passed via props from the NestedList, whose state determines whether its child CollapsibleList components are open or not.

Problem: CollapsibleList props (which come from state of the NestedList) don't change on changing state of said NestedList. I have examined the properties in the debugger and I have been stuck for days. In other words, the CollapsibleList element appears on the browser window, but clicking it only changes the state of the NestedList, and the props of the CollapsibleList doesn't change, and thus it doesn't appear/disappear. I think it has something to do with creating the CollapsibleLists in the socket.io callback, bound with 'this', since the 'collapsed' prop of the CollapsibleList depends on this.state[restaurantId].collapsed. Source is below, if it is unclear I can add more explanation.

```
class CollapsibleList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <List>
        <ListItem
          button
          onClick={() => {
            this.props.collapseEventHandler(this.props.restaurantId);
          }}
        >
          <ListItemText primary="Collapse me!" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <Collapse in={!this.props.collapsed} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <ListItemText primary="Hello World!" />
          </Collapse>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    );
  }
}

class NestedList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //let menuData = props.menuData.map()
    this.toggleVisiblity = this.toggleVisiblity.bind(this);
    this.arrayOfMenus = [];
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    socket.on(
      "menu-arrived",
      function(menuJson) {
        if (menuJson.response.menu.menus.items) {
          let restaurantId = menuJson.restaurant_id;
          //let menuId = menuJson.response.menu.menus.items[0].menuId;
          this.arrayOfMenus.push(
            <CollapsibleList
              collapsed={this.state[restaurantId].collapsed}
              collapseEventHandler={this.toggleVisiblity}
              restaurantId={restaurantId}
              key={restaurantId}
            />
          );
          this.setState(function(prevState, props) {
            return {
              [restaurantId]: {
                collapsed: prevState[restaurantId].collapsed,
                updated: true
              }
            };
          });
        }
      }.bind(this)
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getNearbyRestaurantRawData().then(
      function(rawData) {
        let restaurantIds = parseOutVenueIds(rawData);
        let menusOpen = {};
        for (let i = 0; i < restaurantIds.length; i++) {
          menusOpen[restaurantIds[i]] = {
            collapsed: true
          };
        }
        this.setState(menusOpen, () => {
          socket.emit("get-menus", {
            ids: restaurantIds
          });
        });
      }.bind(this)
    );
  }

  toggleVisiblity(restaurantId) {
    this.setState(function(prevState, props) {
      let newState = Object.assign({}, prevState);
      newState[restaurantId].collapsed = !prevState[restaurantId].collapsed;
      return newState;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <List>
        <React.Fragment>
          <CssBaseline>{this.arrayOfMenus}</CssBaseline>
        </React.Fragment>
      </List>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of pushing JSX to `this.arrayOfMenus`, you should keep all the `restaurantId` in the array in state instead, and derive your JSX from that in the render method.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, as I would avoid any 'this.state' issues, and I will try that. I'm just really curious as to why the props aren't changing with the rerender, considering that the 'this' binding is accurate.

Comment: You are pushing `<CollapsibleList ... />` to an array, so you will never create new React elements for `CollapsibleList` when the props or state change. You should always derive your JSX from state and props in the render method.

Comment: I see, so my understanding was previously flawed. If the jsx is not derived within the render method, react cannot replace/modify it directly?

Comment: [JSX is just a bunch of `React.createElement` calls under the hood](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwYQ9gNhCGAODOBLARhApgGUfALgKAAICBjSGBNAEwF4BvHAC2wDpdoc0BtAJzTYFdu0AHY4AkpQC6zUlDjwqAXzwB6AHxA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=). If you just create elements and store them in an array, new elements will never be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing `CollapsibleList` React elements to an array on the instance, which means that new React elements will not be created and returned from the render method when state or props change.

You should always derive your UI from state and props in the render method instead.

**Example**

```
class NestedList extends React.Component {
  state = { restaurantIds: [] };

  componentWillMount() {
    socket.on("menu-arrived", menuJson => {
      if (menuJson.response.menu.menus.items) {
        let restaurantId = menuJson.restaurant_id;
        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {
            restaurantIds: [...prevState.restaurantIds, restaurantId],
            [restaurantId]: {
              collapsed: prevState[restaurantId].collapsed,
              updated: true
            }
          };
        });
      }
    });
  }

  // ...

  render() {
    return (
      <List>
        <React.Fragment>
          <CssBaseline>
            {this.state.restaurantIds.map(restaurantId => (
              <CollapsibleList
                collapsed={this.state[restaurantId].collapsed}
                collapseEventHandler={this.toggleVisiblity}
                restaurantId={restaurantId}
                key={restaurantId}
              />
            ))}
          </CssBaseline>
        </React.Fragment>
      </List>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand where I was going wrong before. All render could see was instructions to display an array of existing components. All the change in state meant was another call to the render.

Comment: Yes! I appreciate the immediate help. I wish I could upvote, but it looks like I need more reputation to have any visible impact. I will mark this as accepted ASAP. Truly appreciate the help. I liked the babel transpile link in the comments.